# Annotation applicable to specific data type

Tags: java, annotations

I don't know if the question I am asking is really stupid. But here it is:

I would like to write a custom annotation which should be applicable to a specific type. For example, if I have a class A, then I would like to have an annotation that can be applied on objects of A.

Something like this:

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, //WHAT_ELSE_HERE_?})
public @interface MyAnnotation {
   String attribute1();
}

public class X {
   @MyAnnotation (attribute1="...") //SHOULDN'T BE POSSIBLE
   String str;
   @MyAnnotation (attribute1="..") //PERFECTLY VALID
   A aObj1;
   @MyAnnotation (attribute1="...") //SHOULDN'T BE POSSIBLE
   B bObj1;
}
```

Is that possible at all?

Comment: Not possible. But why would you want to do that?

Comment: Check out a suggestion that I have for you to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks NarendraPathai and @hexafraction. I was expecting that, but was still optimistic thinking there may be something outside of what I know.

Comment: @Narenda Why? Because you only want your annotation applied to a specific field type

E.g. boolean - e.g. Master Annotation indicates whether bean is active / inactive - any other type would not make sense

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not possible. [`@Target`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Target.html) uses `ElementType[]`, and [`ElementType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html) is an enum, so you can't modify it. It does not contain a consideration for only specific field types.

You can, however, discard the annotation at runtime, or raise runtime exceptions about it.

Answer (score 7):

That is *not possible* in Java.

But you have an option to write your own [annotation processor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/package-summary.html) if you want to check the correctness of the annotations before runtime.

> Annotation processing is a hook in the compile process, to analyse the
>   source code for user defined annotations and handle then (by producing
>   compiler errors, compiler warning, emmiting source code, byte code
>   ..).

[A basic tutorial on Annotation Processing](http://programmaticallyspeaking.com/playing-with-java-annotation-processing.html).

Comment: I do have my custom annotation processor and am also discarding the annotation on the fields that I am not interested in, but I was looking if there is some other approach much simpler than that.